# Why does Get-Item $PSScriptRoot throws exception, when run by Jenkins master?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that has a promotion that runs a Powershell script.

The Promotion Process Action is Windows PowerShell:

```
& "\\myserver\mypath\$ENV:BUILD_NUMBER\\deployStuff.ps1" -environment "Dev"
```

The beginning of the script:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Environment
)

Write-Host "Deploy  - Environment = $Environment"
$root = (Get-Item $PSScriptRoot)
Write-Host "root = $root"
```

Nothing very exciting. Except that when I check "Restrict where this promotion process can be run" and specify one of my slaves, it works, and if I uncheck it, or specify that I run it on the master, I get an exception:

```
Started by user jdege
Building on master in workspace E:\jenkins_home\jobs\Promote Development Branch\workspace
Promoting Promote Development Branch #18
[workspace] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\KORCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson2695983892011285716.ps1'"
Deploy - Environment = Dev
Get-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At \\myserver\mypath\$ENV:BUILD_NUMBER\\deployStuff.ps1:6 char:18
+ $root = (Get-Item <<<<  $PSScriptRoot)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell. 
   Commands.GetItemCommand
```

Why would this work on the slave but not on the master?

---

Mathias suggested I try $MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot.

My changed script:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Environment
)

$root = Get-Item $PSScriptRoot
Write-Host "root - $root"
$root2 = Get-Item $MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot
Write-Host "root2 - $root2"
```

My output:

```
Started by user jdege
Building on master in workspace E:\jenkins_home\jobs\Promote Development Branch\workspace
Promoting Promote Development Branch #25
[workspace] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\KORCOM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson1494277122445286804.ps1'"
try PSScriptRoot
Get-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At \\ch-vmfile1\PublishedBuilds\kt_everything\development\8\deploy_bats\deploy_bats\deployMigrator.
ps1:6 char:17
+ $root = Get-Item <<<<  $PSScriptRoot
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell. 
   Commands.GetItemCommand

root - 
try MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot
root2 - 
Get-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At \\ch-vmfile1\PublishedBuilds\kt_everything\development\8\deploy_bats\deploy_bats\deployMigrator.
ps1:18 char:20
+ $parent = (Get-Item <<<<  $PSScriptRoot).parent.parent.FullName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell. 
   Commands.GetItemCommand

Get-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At \\ch-vmfile1\PublishedBuilds\kt_everything\development\8\deploy_bats\deploy_bats\deployMigrator.
ps1:33 char:29
+ . (Join-Path -Path (Get-Item <<<<  $PSScriptRoot) -ChildPath deployFunctions.ps1)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell. 
   Commands.GetItemCommand
```

In other words, I'm seeing the same error with $MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot that I do with $PSScriptRoot.

Comment: What version of Windows and/or PowerShell is your Jenkins server running?

Comment: Master is running "Windows Server 2019 Standard 1809", PSVersion: 5.1.17763.316, Slave is running "Windows Server 2016 Standard 1607", PsVersion: 5.1.14393.3053.

Comment: Curious. Does replacing it with `$MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot` work?

Comment: Try this... $Root = Resolve-Path "$PSScriptRoot\.."